# Why vue showing `[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined"` error?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-quill-editor

I am new to Vuejs & trying to use vue-quill-editor. Here I am trying to Use Quill editor Component in other components.

**WysiwygInput.vue**

```
 <quill-editor
  :options="{
    placeholder: placeholder,
  }"
  :content="content"
  v-on:change="$emit('change', $event.target.content)"
></quill-editor>
```

**App.vue**

```
<wysiwyg-input v-model="content" placeholder="Post Content" />
```

This is showing the following error in the console.

> [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined"

I know this is something basic but can't solve this.

[CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-quill-osmanrafi-7c6fl?file=/src/App.vue:106-168)

Answer (score 2):

You should add an arrow function as handler with `$event` as parameter and emit the `text` property as `$emit` payload :

```
  v-on:change="($event)=>$emit('change', $event.text)"
```

Comment: That's working! But the problem is the while making an input, the cursor always going to the first position, the same thing happening for deleting. Please have a look at the sandbox example.

Comment: That's an issue with `contenteditable`: anytime the `innerHTML` is programmatically updated, the cursor position is lost. You probably can't use `v-model` for that purpose, as it will always trigger re-rendering of the contentedtiable DOM tree.

Comment: could you please suggest any solution?  @Terry